# Slow speed on Raspberry Pi 2, WiFi to WiFi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi 2 as router, with usb adapters:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:1006 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN322G v3 / TL-WN422G v2 802.11g [Atheros AR9271]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

TP-Link is used to connect to WiFi, Edimax is to host AP.

From Pi to Internet I get up to: 40/40 Mbit/s connection (with VPN, CPU bottleneck)
From Laptop to Pi: 65/65 Mbit/s (Edimax dongle is the bottleneck)

But from Laptop, through my Pi, to Internet, my connection is only max 4/10 Mbit/s. (CPU not even 50%)

Both adapters are plugged directly to Pi, without any powered hub.
I use 5V, 2.1A adapter.
Pi's red led is not blinking, current is stable.

The question:
Why is the Laptop-Internet speed so slow, and how can I make it faster?

Comment: Simple answer: they are interfering with each other. You are using a wireless repeater which will at least halve your connection speed even under ideal conditions. Don't use two cards, you will only make things slower.

Comment: They use different channels: 1 and 11.
Or even with these settings, the interference is this bad?

Comment: Using different channels makes it worse. Near-field sideband interference occurs over the entire band if the adapters are too close (less than ~2 metres).

Comment: Routing isn't relevant. Two wireless networks physically close to each other on the same band is bad. Your easiest solution is to get a 5Ghz adapter, or place the 2.4Ghz adapters at least 2 metres apart.

Comment: I'm working with existing things, buying new isn't an option.
I'll try the WiFi to ethernet routing.

Comment: Use the Pi as a router, wire its ethernet into edimax as a single point of transmission. Job done.

Comment: Yes, it can be the easyest solution, but I don't have any ethernet connection, where I want to use. But WiFi to Ethernet is working.